# Visual studio 2010, Outlook 2010 and Windows Application, Return Emails

Tags: vb.net, winforms, outlook

At present I have wrote an application (in-house CRM, vb .net 2010) which allows me to send emails under the selected customer & I categorised these emails.

As these are categorised I can return data to display email history in my program by using search criteria:

Dim oMail As Outlook.MAPIFolder = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail)

Dim sSearch As String
        sSearch = "[Categories] = '" + "[" + tAccount.Text.Trim + "]" + "(" + tShipTo.Text.Trim + ")'"

Dim oItems As Outlook.Items = oMail.Items.Restrict(sSearch)

However the limitation to the above is it only looks at sent items & no other folder.
My ideal solution would be to display all email correspondence for a certain contact.

Could you please advise how I could add this feature to my program

Answer (score 0):

I know this probably isn't quite what you were after but you could copy all emails into a sql database and query that instead ?
Also tends to work much better if you have large numbers of emails to store/ manage.

Comment: In outlook 2010 there is a new ‘people panel’. When you click on a contact it will show you previous emails. It would be good if this could incorporate this feature in my program. 
If this can’t be done I’ll take your advise & use sql